# How was the impenetrable force field penetrated?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In *The Man In The Yellow Suit* (S01E09), Team-Flash uses a Tachyon Field as an impenetrable force field believing that

> it will contain The Reverse Flash,

which it seems to do. But

> The Reverse Flash somehow pulls Dr Wells into the field and begins attacking him. Everyone begins yelling at Cisco to drop the field. Cisco momentarily argues that doing so will allow The Reverse Flash to escape, but he's already demonstrated that he could get out.

How was the field penetrated, or was it not really impenetrable to begin with?

Comment: I was wondering this myself, as well as a few other things.  My guess is, that Wells knew that he couldn't be contained within the barrier and that the entire thing was an act put on by Wells(he and Reverse-Flash are one in the same apparently).  Either that or Wells built in a glitch to allow Reverse-Flash to escape temporarily and 'capture' him(Wells).

Comment: Probably using an impenetrable force field penetrator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a hologram.  The Reverse Flash and the force field were just an illusion created by the Reverse Flash to enable him to appear to be in two places at once.  One in the force field, the other (spoilers for *Flash* S1E15)

> sitting in his wheelchair as Harrison Wells.

Answer (score 0):

I think the force field was just an illusion and wasn't ever even there so that Dr.Hawthorn aka Dr.Wells could run so fast that he appeared to be in the same place. He must have been running faster than light to be able to run from the wheel chair to the fake trap and back and forth.  This could be the only explanation because as the reverse flash fought Barry Dr.Wells was still in the back laying down. One think that didn't make since is the fact that he was still cut up when he was being bandaged up latter in that episode, this seems trippy because Barry healed from a broken wrist in 3 hours so he should have healed from those scrapes way less time than that.

Comment: Hawthorn? You mean Thawne?